# Where can I find my Firebase reference URL in Firebase account?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

In the third last line of the below code, how can I find the firebase URL. I am not able to find it. Can anyone provide me the best link on how to setup firebase facebook login with android.

```
public void saveUser() {
    //Add YOUR Firebase Reference URL instead of the following URL
    Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://androidbashfirebase.firebaseio.com/"); //<---- How to find this
    myFirebaseRef = myFirebaseRef.child("users").child(getId());
    myFirebaseRef.setValue(this);
}
```

Comment: Try this -http://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/

Answer (score 54):

For **Firestore** I tried this to find get the databaseUrl and it works for me:

Go to `Cloud Firestore` tab and take the id as circled in the image.

[image]

Then the `databaseURL` is `https://football-f559a.firebaseio.com`

Tested this with Python and Firebase Admin sdk

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("./firebase-admin.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://football-f559a.firebaseio.com'
})

db = firestore.client()

for k in db.collection("countries").get():
    print(k.id, k.to_dict())
```

Output:

```
A {'name': 'aaaaa'}
C {'name': 'C2'}
```

**UPDATE:**

Apparently I can use any databaseURL and it still works:

```
'databaseURL': 'https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com'
```

Comment: That's because if you look in the sample snippet provided by firestore, databaseURL is no longer required for authentication

Answer (score 41):

You should have done searching by yourself first. Here you are,

1. Open [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com)

[image]

2. Select your app, and go to database, marked is the url you need.

[image]

**For UPDATED UI**

Follow the below steps to get it in new UI of Firebase Console:

1. Go to Database section
2. Tap Cloud Firebase (marked 1 in picture) and select Realtime Database
3. Marked 2 is the URL

[image]

Answer (score 39):

**In the New UI (Nov-2019)**

You need to select **project settings** in the **Left Corner**.

[image]

Then **Scroll Down** to **Apps Section**

Select **Config**, Then you can get all the information.

[image]

Comment: thank you, they keep changing it - I was a bit lost not having done this for almost 2 years

Comment: I can find the "databaseURL" for one of my projects here, but I cannot find it for a different firebase project.  Is there some reason it'd not be displayed here?

Answer (score 12):

When you create you Firebase database, it will be created with a unique URL ending in **firebaseio.com**. The URL of the database follows the format:

```
https://<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseio.com/
```

What you want to do is go to the Database tab, switch from **Cloud Firestore (Beta)** to **Realtime Database** using the select button. You will be able to see your DB URL as shown in the following:

[image]

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

For folks who stumble upon this issue in 2021:
Google no longer seems to requires "databaseURL" for authentication. See Firestore SDK config file snapshot below
[image]

That said, for authentication, you can use any of the following: projectId, storageBucket, serviceAccountID etc.

Documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin

Comment: For anyone in 2023 ending up here while trying to get pyrebase to work in python. I found you have to have a databaseURL and storageBucket key value pairs when setting up your config object.  But I am not using either so passed None as the value and could authenticate fine.

Answer (score 9):

> **NOTE**: Same for both old and new UI of the firebase.

1. Go to Authentication Tab and click on **WEB SETUP** button on the right upper side of the screen.
   [image]
2. Now you will see a dialog box opened, you can see a lot of information fields in it and you will also be able to see a field **databaseUrl**, this is your required field.
   [image]

Answer (score 7):

> **Update**: UI of firebase has been changed so follow below steps

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't created Firebase account already, Just Create it first. Head over to console and add a new App over there if not added. If you already got an app just click on it and go to dashboard.

In Dashboard click on Database and you will see the Firebase Reference URL over there. Refer to below Screenshot

[image: Firebase Reference URL]

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The UI has changed now. So can you tell where to find it now?

Answer (score 2):

As  Neeraj Chand said:
Now there are two kinds of databases on firebase - **firestore** and **Realtime** Database. If you are on firestore mode (default) then u might not find the url to db directly. S*witch to Realtime Database* from the **blue dropdown** on the top and you will get the url
[watch this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aegg6.png)

Answer (score 2):

If your firebase location is **other than** `us-central1`, the url must be more slightly changed, such as `https://androidbashfirebase.asia-northeast1.firebasedatabase.app`.
See examples on [Select locations for your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations).

Answer (score 1):

[image: now 2021 ui like this]

Just click the Realtime Database link on the left side and create a firebase database. After successful creation, you will get a link for your database ending with firebaseio.com. Make use of it. This is 2021 update

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of databases in Firebase. One of them is the `Realtime Database`. The URL for that database is here:

[image]

The other one, `Firestore Database`,  it can be constructed using this template:

```
https://[project-id].firebaseio.com
```

Answer (score -6):

```
let connectedRef = Database.database(url: "your url")
```

Comment: OP asked where to find the URL, not where to put it.