# error: constructor FirebaseListAdapter in class FirebaseListAdapter<T> cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> error: constructor FirebaseListAdapter in class FirebaseListAdapter
>   cannot be applied to given types; required:
>   FirebaseListOptions found:
>   MainActivity,Class,int,DatabaseReference reason: actual
>   and formal argument lists differ in length where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends Object declared in class FirebaseListAdapter

my code:

```
adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
                R.layout.message, 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) 
{
            @Override
 protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {

       // Get references to the views of message.xml
               TextView messageText = 
(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                TextView messageUser = 
(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = 
(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

      listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

i having latest google services n repositories.
and import all statements:

```
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
```

here is Build.gradle

```
    //add library
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
```

help me resolve this error on firebaseadapter.

Comment: can we see your app level build.gradle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase List Adapter Constructor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243957/firebase-list-adapter-constructor-error)

Comment: Thanks resolving my issue . Vote my post n like my profile. Peter Habbad. Levi albuquerque..

Comment: It may work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243957/firebase-list-adapter-constructor-error

Answer (score 0):

i have you whole solution. i have face right now and i solved it with some library version. i hope this work for you too.

first of all user below dependencies,

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
```

Import

```
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter;
```

main code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Firebase rootRef;
    FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> mListAdapter;
    EditText mEditText;
    ListView listView;
    String username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        username = getUsername();

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        rootRef = new Firebase("<Reference url>");

        mListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<com.example.dev_ramiz_1707.testfirebase.ChatMessage>(this, com.example.dev_ramiz_1707.testfirebase.ChatMessage.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, rootRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, com.example.dev_ramiz_1707.testfirebase.ChatMessage model, int position) {
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getName());
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.getText());
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
        com.example.dev_ramiz_1707.testfirebase.ChatMessage message = new com.example.dev_ramiz_1707.testfirebase.ChatMessage(username, text);
        rootRef.push().setValue(message);
        mEditText.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mListAdapter.cleanup();
    }

    public String getUsername() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = MainActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String Username = sharedPref.getString("username","User-Name");
        return Username;

    }

}
```

don't just copy this code also learn how it work too.

in your code there is updated library and in updated library has new classes which does not contain FirebaseListAdapter. thats why you need to put individual firebase library.

if your don't know how to create Reference url then follow this :- [Where can I find my Firebase reference URL in Firebase account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168564/where-can-i-find-my-firebase-reference-url-in-firebase-account)

I hope this help better.