# Firebase Realtime Database from Android setValue not working

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use the realtime database for the first time. The set value function is not working for me.

I already updated the writing rules in the following way :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
        Integer Age = 24;
        FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference sReference = mDatabase.getReference();
        sReference.child("Users").child("George").child("Age").setValue(Age)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Data stored", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

When I print out the reference it is correct. However neither the OnSucces nor the OnFailure is triggered.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could it be the events are attached to it later than the action executed, is the set happening sooner? Could do it the way the tutorial is recomending? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: If neither the OnSucces nor the OnFailure is triggered, then is most probably you don't have an internet connection on the device.

Comment: @AlexMamo I think the Internet connection is not the problem, as the authentification works fine and I also tried it on the emulator

Comment: @AntonKrug it is the first time the set is happening, tried it with various template writing codes as well

Comment: Can you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check the logcat output of your app of the moment when the `setValue` call happens for any relevant messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. The database is located in Europe. Apparently I did not specify the URL in the getInstance() method, which seems to be required in this case.

Comment: Great you posted the answer after figuring it out so if somebody has a similar issue they will not find a 'solved' question without an answer.

Comment: Thank you @Alex.  I couldn't figure this out for 8 hours.

Comment: working perfectly for me, Database location: Singapore (asia-southeast1)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a firebase realtime database bug. It happens when you select Europe server (beta) instead of USA. And occures with no errors or warning of any kind.

Fix as mentioned above. Use direct link from firebase console in you database instance (change xxx with your project data from firebase console realtime database section):

```
// Write a message to the database
val database = Firebase.database("https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/")
val myRef = database.getReference("message")

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: This... I can't believe I have wasted an entire day not understanding why my database was not working at all... no logs, nothing. Thank you sir, you have probably saved me even more wasted time. Google gives absolutely no warning for this when setting other db locations, how unprofessional, they think that somehow we can imagine the cause of these issues out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Ensure your sha1 is added to firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application)
2. [Enable signIn method in Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8tEaAQ8Mfg)
3. [Enable Android Device Verification in Google Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/androidcheck.googleapis.com/overview?authuser=3&folder=&organizationId=&project=iimi-campus)
4. Ensure internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml
5. Provide db url in getInstance(). [How to find Database URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40168644/14055097)

   ```
   DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("<<Insert Databse URL here>>").getReference();
   ```
6. Restart your emulator and modem/router
7. debug with logs

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are specifying database URL while getting database instance like -

```
val database = Firebase.database("<url_here>")
val ref = database.reference
```

and then perform setValue() function over it say -

```
ref.child("users").child(uid).setValue(user)
```

This worked in my case!

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem and I got the answer hope it's not too late for others.....

1. After Creating Realtime database go to Project Settings in firebase dashboard -> Project Overview -> Gear Icon -> Project Settings and scroll down and check google-services.json file and download it again and replace with same place in android studio -> select project view -> in app folder (you know the drill) .... and clean - rebuild app again...... it worked for me after hours.....
2. in short just redownload and replace google-services.json again and clean - rebuild project....