# Firestore 9.6.1: Could not reach backend... React Native (Android Virtual Device)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I don't seem to get why when it comes to the avd it can't connect to the firestore. I did try to setup a react js test app and use the same code just to console log result and it works fine.
Also after a few minutes the metro console will have a warning Firestore (9.6.1): Connection WebChannel transport errored: {Some very long object}

Comment: 9.6.1 is extremely old.  The first thing you should do is upgrade to the latest.   See the release notes.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson its React-Native (which 9.6.1 is the current and latest version for javascript sdk)

Comment: Your question should contain enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the issue as you see it.  Please edit it to be complete.  Right now, we don't know anything about what you've configured or tried to get to this error

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete to understand/reproduce the issue. Request you to provide more information on the question to make it understandable. Also, you might refer to the [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594133/react-native-to-firestore-firestore-8-2-1-connection-webchannel-transport-er) which also talks about Webchannel transport error in React Native.

Comment: using 'firestore/lite' fixed the issue

Comment: Nice to hear your issue got resolved. It will be helpful for the Community members if you can post an answer.

Comment: Hi, Its not really an answer. because i cannot use the full firestore functions. 
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore' -> this cause an issue but using
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore/lite' -> works fine. but again i cant use something like onSnapShot()