# Adding document in firebase firestore via react native is not working, but not throwing error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a react native project and am using firebase v9.

I am trying to add a user object to my user collection when a user is created via the sign up screen, but it is not adding in the database, and not throwing any errors either.

Here is my firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
};

let app;

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  app = firebase.app();
}

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export {db, auth};
```

I know that these connection details are correct because my firebase authentication is working correctly.

Here is my sign in screen where I attempt to add to the database.

```
const SignUp = ({navigation}) => {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const createUser = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function (user) {
          var user = auth.currentUser;
          logUser(user);
          navigation.navigate('Login');
        });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };

  async function logUser(user) {
    await addDoc(collection(db, 'users'), JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));
  }
```

If I don't put JSON.parse/JSON.stringify, it is throwing an error saying firebase is called with invalid data, expected object, but it was a custom user object. So I know it is hitting that part of the codebase.

I have also went into my firestore 'rules' section on firebase console and changed it to requests go through for all:

```
      allow read, write: if true;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try write inside try block. i guess when it has finished there User data is cleaned probably or try  in loguser write any data to database With that we can be understand  function is working or not

Comment: Do you mean try writing something like user: "test" inside my addDoc function, just to see if it works? I tried that and it is not adding anything to the db.

Comment: Can you also intialize Firestore as `const db = firebase.firestore();` so it's same as auth? Not the issue but might be good imo

Comment: I have one more suggestion that use these rules while writing the codes to avoid errors.                              `".read": true,  
    ".write":true, `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `compat` version of Firebase SDK but also using the new Modular SDK syntax. Try using only 1 version of the SDK as shown below:

```
import { db } from "..path/to/firebase/firebase.js"

async function logUser(user) {
  await db.collection("users").add(user)
}
```

I would recommend [upgrading to Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) as compat version might be removed in newer versions.

Comment: This eventually worked. I will add that I had to add 
firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true }); to my firebase initialization. See here for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594133/react-native-to-firestore-firestore-8-2-1-connection-webchannel-transport-er