# Firestore WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' Error - 400 Bad Request

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, web, google-cloud-firestore

The reason why this is all code btw is because stack overflow was acting weird and this was the solution

Description:I've been encountering an issue with Firestore while trying to retrieve data from my Firestore database using the Firebase web SDK. I've gone through my code, Firestore security rules, and CORS settings, but I'm still facing the same error. This only occurs on my web platform

```
 Error: [2023-08-11T01:10:26.900Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.22.1): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x73ac5adc transport errored:
```

```
            FutureBuilder<User?>(

              future: Provider.of(context)!.auth.getCurrentUser(),

              builder: (context, snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return displayUserInformation(context, snapshot.data);
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),

            StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(

              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance

                  .collection('users')

                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)

                  .snapshots(),

              builder: (context, snapshot) {

                if (!snapshot.hasData) {

                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

                } else {

                  final data = snapshot.data?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;

                  if (data != null && data.containsKey('gallery')) {

                    List<String> imageList = List<String>.from(data['gallery']);

                    return Padding(

                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),

                      child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(

                        shrinkWrap: true,

                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

                        crossAxisCount: 2,

                        mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,

                        crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,

                        itemCount: imageList.length,

                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                          double aspectRatio = determineAspectRatio(imageList[index]);

                          return GestureDetector(

                            onTap: () {

                              deletePicture(context, imageList[index]);

                            },

                            child: ClipRRect(

                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),

                              child: Container(

                                decoration: BoxDecoration(

                                  boxShadow: [

                                    BoxShadow(

                                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),

                                      blurRadius: 8.0,

                                      spreadRadius: 2.0,

                                      offset: Offset(0, 2),

                                    ),

                                  ],

                                ),

                                child: Image.network(

                                  imageList[index],

                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,

                                  errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {

                                    return Container(color: Colors.grey);

                                  },

                                ),

                              ),

                            ),

                          );

                        },

                        staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),

                      ),

                    );

                  } else {

                    return Container();

                  }

                }

              },

            ),

          ],

        ),

      ),









  Widget displayUserInformation(BuildContext context, User? user) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user?.uid).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final active = snapshot.data!.data()?['story'] ?? 'anonymous';
            final mission = snapshot.data!.data()?['mission'] ?? 'anonymous';
            final based = snapshot.data!.data()?['based'] ?? 'anonymous';
            final profession = snapshot.data!.data()?['profression'] ?? 'anonymous';
            final userName = snapshot.data!.data()?['userName'] ?? 'anonymous';
            final profilePicUrl = snapshot.data!.data()?['profile_pic'];

            return Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profilePicUrl ?? ''),
                    radius: 50,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 16),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text(
                          '$userName',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 109, 133, 23),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
```

```
Firestore Security Rules:`rules_version = '2';service cloud.firestore {match /databases/{database}/documents {match /{document=**} {allow read, write: if request.auth != null;}
```

```
Here's my CORS configuration for Cloud Storage:`[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "HEAD"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The classical solution to this issue is to explicitly initialize your Firestore API object with the `experimentalForceLongPolling` flag set to true (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Settings ), which in theory means that it *should not even be setting up* the WebSocket / WebChannelConnection / Remote Procedure Call system, and instead relying on ordinary web requests to send and retrieve data.  Since I don't recognize the exact dialect of your code sample, I won't try to construct a copypasta solution, but it will likely involve establishing your firestore API object with an explicit Init call that takes a Settings argument, rather than via a Get call that returns with default settings (and note that if your code uses multiple independent Get calls in various places, the Init call will need to happen once and only once at a point before any Get call).

Unfortunately, my current experience is that even with long polling "forced," the API will still do something with WebChannelConnection / RPC and that this will still throw warnings periodically in largescale deploys.  If you still see the data by and large reaching your back-end, I wouldn't sweat the occasional warning, since firestore is designed to be robust against connectivity issues.

*Edit:* There is also a telling answer a ways down on [React Native to firestore: Firestore (8.2.1): Connection WebChannel transport errored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594133/react-native-to-firestore-firestore-8-2-1-connection-webchannel-transport-er) indicating that this may occur when you are listening on a malformed document path, or a path that does not correspond to any extant document.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a problem with web version. I added experimentalForceLongPolling in index.html:

```
  <script>
    ...
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true })
    ...
</script>
```