# Cannot find ‘Settings’ in scope for stripe express account subscriptions documentation

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am going through Stripe's documentation to create an express account (Stripe Connect). I made it to [step 2.3](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide#redirect-your-user-to-the-account-link-url).

But get the following error (I'm using iOS, Swift):

> Cannot find 'Settings' in scope

for this line:

```
if let url = URL(string: Settings.BackendAPIBaseURL)?.appendingPathComponent("onboard-user") {
```

(Full code found on [step 2.3 of link provided](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide#redirect-your-user-to-the-account-link-url).)

Clearly there is no class called 'Settings', but nothing is provided in the Stripe Documentation it seems...

Comment: I think the code is just implying that you would have your own Settings class that would have a `BackendAPIBaseURL()` method. I'd recommend just skipping that and passing the URL to hit to reach your server

Comment: My backend is with firebase functions, what would its URL be? Or where do I find it?

Comment: Not sure how Firebase is configured but that isn't really Stripe specific. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66488535/1606729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can do one is going to your console and go to functions and they will be listed or when you deploy your functions it’s will tell you as well.